# How to make Google-map style pin for an high-resolution on Android OS?

Tags: android

I would like to design an application that does annotations on a high-resolution image. In particular, I am looking for UI elements that mimic google-map style pins and tags. Are there any existing UI APIs that I can use for that in Android already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with the default Android MapView there is no element available to directly add an overlay like the pins and the text-markers in the google map app, without creating your own image assets and use those.

Maybe this answer: [Expanding Overlay Marker on Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286983/expanding-overlay-marker-on-google-maps/3880470#3880470) can give you an idea to solve your problem. The projects that are linked use [9patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) images to create a custom map overlay.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information in your question to determine what you want. Are you doing graphics or using the Google maps interface? Check out 2D graphics for the non-maps graphics. Check out Overlay draw for maps.